# Adding header information in MongoDB Kafka connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am using the following connector to get data from MongoDB to my Kafka topic:

```
{
        "class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
        "type": "source",
        "version": "1.10.0"
}
```

And the record coming to the Kafka topic has empty header information:

```
headers: {}
```

What I need here is to add a hard-coded header information in the connector, so that all records processed by the connector can have header similar to:

```
headers: {"Source": "MongoDB"}
```

I come across a transformation called InsertHeader: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/insertheader.html#insertheader that seems to do exactly what I need, however, when I try to use it with my connector, it is throwing the error:

```
Invalid value org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertHeader for configuration transforms.InsertHeader.type: Class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertHeader could not be found.
```

It is stated that **InsertHeader is not currently available for managed connectors**, is this the reason why it is not useable?

And what are the alternatives that I can use?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "manged connector", I assume you are referring to Confluent Cloud.

In that case, you need to self manage to get control over what plugins/transforms are available for any connector to use

Alternatively, deploy without transforms. Use other tools to consume and insert headers, and write to new topics

Comment: I was able to identify an additional JAR file that contains the required InsertHeader transformation. Adding that to /lib folder allows usage of that transformation.